# why pip install turtle (graphics) error

Tags: installation, python, pip

I get the following error when installing `turtle`, what should I do?

```
$ sudo pip install turtle --proxy http://10.144.1.10:8080
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip install --user` instead.
Collecting turtle
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/f0/21a42e9e424d24bdd0e509d5ed3c7dfb8f47d962d9c044dba903b0b4a26f/turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-smo98rwf/turtle/setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-smo98rwf/turtle/
```

I am using Fedora 31, and pip version:

```
$ pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Some other python library can be installed successfully, like:

```
$ sudo pip install scipy --proxy http://10.144.1.10:8080
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip install --user` instead.
Collecting scipy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/9d/a606dc7b17ef0b7326afd128e132b7a483d5611da603334842df75d92d3c/scipy-1.4.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.1MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 26.1MB 824kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages (from scipy) (1.17.4)
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0
```

BTW, turtle seems not installed within my python...

```
$ python
Python 3.7.5 (default, Dec 15 2019, 17:54:26) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle'
>>>
```

Summary:

`turtle graphics` is a part of python3 standard library, no need to install it. If `import turtle` shows error like "No module named...", it could be solved by, for example in Fedora, `sudo dnf install python3-tkinter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Turtle graphics](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/turtle.html) is already included in the Python standard library.

Also install the *python3-tkinter* package from the default Fedora repositories. python3-tkinter is a module for writing portable GUI applications with Python 3.x using Tk. Then try to run this Python code for drawing a circle.

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.circle(50)
```

The package that you tried to install with `sudo pip install turtle` is an HTTP proxy package. It's not the right package for Turtle graphics.

Comment: Which one do you want, Turtle graphics or Turtle HTTP proxy?

Comment: I want Turtle graphics

Comment: Try installing the *python3-tkinter* package in Fedora from the default Fedora repositories. python3-tkinter is a module for writing portable GUI applications with Python 3.x using Tk. Then try to run the Python code for drawing a circle in my answer.

Comment: Yes, after install the python3-tkinter package, the problem solved. Thank you!